# Bootstrap 3 - Overlapping Content (Clearfix?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue in my HTML (Bootstrap) where a three column footer appears fine on most desktops, but collapses/overlaps on smaller screen sizes (tablet/mobile).

I use `float: left;` for a couple footer elements - perhaps it's related.

I can fix it with `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the offending elements, but this would break the three column layout on desktop.

What am I missing?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Footer]

Example:

http://www.bootply.com/YRCLoHI7Uw

Comment: You only have `md` classes like `col-md-6` in your footer. You'll at least need to have column classes for the smallest , `xs`, layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your row and the child divs float:left. I suppose that solves your question. Let me know if that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: I don't know what's the downvote is for. row,col-md-3,6,3 with style float:left seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Not from me. It resolved the issue - is `float: left;` on a `col-XX-Y` the right way to do this though (as opposed to a hack)?

Comment: So you mean to say you want to resolve this only though boostrap classes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in you code

Problem:

You are using `px` while giving `width`, `padding` and `margin` to the `<address>` and `.box`.

Solution:

You *should always* use `%` or `em` while making responsive design. `%` for `width` and `em` for `padding` and `margin` because `%` and `em` will expand and contract according to the `width`.

Comment: Oh yes. To the OP, instead of giving height and width give col-xx-12 to the inner divs if you want it to take up the space of the outer div. I assume you already know that.

Comment: @Jason Does that mean I can nest a `col-md-12` within a `col-md-6`? Or, are you referring to putting a `col-md-12` in the `div.tweets`?

Comment: @okoboko you can nest `col-md-12` within a `col-md-6`